# trigger ajax event when clicked on HTML `<audio>` element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a project when a user logs in he/she can listen to music. Till here its fine but i would like to store history of user regarding which song he has listened. I have tried using jquery alert but this on click event is not working. Kindly suggest me a way. Here is the image of my project...

[image]

Here is the HTML code: There music data is displayed

```
<?php
         include('code/Confim_login.php'); //ITS FILE NAME

        $login = new Confim_login();   // CREATED THE OBJECT 
  ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" id="music_library">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="8%">#</th>
                        <th title="added date">Date</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>User Added</th>
                        <th>Music</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $login->show_music();
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the jquery event

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".musicid").click(function(){
          alert('clicked');
       });
      });
</script>
```

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php
 function show_music(){
            $data = "";
            if($_SESSION['user_logged'][0]['login_type'] == "Admin"){
                $data .= 'del_single_btn';
            }
            else
            {
                $data .= '';
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM music_library WHERE status=1";

            $res = $this->link->query($sql);
            $k=1;

            if($res->num_rows > 0){

                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $k;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['added_date'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['music_name'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_added'];?></td>
                        <td>
                            <audio class="musicid" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" controls>
                                <source src="code/<?php echo $row['file_path'];?>" type="audio/mpeg" >
                                Your browser does not support the audio element.
                            </audio>
                        </td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-default <?php echo $data?>" style="border:1px solid #d9534f;color:#d9534f;" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
        <?php
                    $k++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
        ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">No Music Files Found</td>
                </tr>
        <?php   
            }
        }

?>
```

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You can add an attribute e.g. `data-music-id` and read it by jQuery in your click event by `$(this).attr('data-music-id')` and POST it with AJAX.

Comment: @BartoszT it shows undefined

Comment: Because `$(this)` refers to an object which you take action on. Try @Exprator's edited ans, it should work fine. Mind your `audio` element should still contain `data-music-id` attribute or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<audio onplay="myFunction(this.data-music-id)">...</audio>
```

and inside

```
myfunction(id){
song_id = id;
get the id and send the ajax
}
```

Comment: it is showing me error as `myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLAudioElement.onplay `

Comment: have you declared the fucntion?? like function myFunction(){ } inside the script tag inside the file

Comment: now the funtion works but it does not fetch the unique music id here is the example of my code `<audio onplay="getdata()" data-music-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" controls>`    `<script>function getdata(){
 
 var music_id = $(this).attr('data-music-id');
 
 alert(music_id);
}</script>`   it shows undefined

Comment: @ Exprator this code works i just added `php ` code inside backets `onplay="getdata('<?php echo $row['id']?>')"` thank you ...